# Bootstrap dropdown button does not work

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap.I am having a problem regarding the drop down button feature.While including the jQuery and bootstrap files from remote servers (i.e. from code.jquery.com, cdnjs.cloudflare.com, maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com) the drop down feature works fine.But while working offline by including the files stored locally, the drop down feature does not work.Please help.Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-level="Toolbar example">

            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg mr-2" role="group" aria-level="Button Group 1">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 1</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 2</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 3</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 4</button>
            </div>

            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg mr-2" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Button 1</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Button 2</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Button 3</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Button 4</button>

                <!--- Nested menu  -->
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="btnGroupAddon">@</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" aria-describedby="btnGroupAddon">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="jquery/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popper/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-level="Toolbar example">

            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg mr-2" role="group" aria-level="Button Group 1">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 1</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 2</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 3</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Button 4</button>
            </div>

            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg mr-2" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Button 1</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Button 2</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Button 3</button>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Button 4</button>

                <!--- Nested menu  -->
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="btnGroupAddon">@</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" aria-describedby="btnGroupAddon">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your src path is correct where your scripts are located?

Comment: Source path is OK. Viewing the source and clicking the links leads to the files.

Comment: I have added an id to the text box.id="something", and added the following code

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#something").click(function() {
            alert("Hi");
        });
    </script> and clicking the text box, it shows an alert box.That means that the jquery is working

Comment: Check what error are you getting in console. If it is 404, then it is not finding src path..Let me know if something else

Comment: its because you dont have the a local version or you dont have copy of the libraries in your folder, have you tried downloading them?

Answer (score 0):

Order of inclusion is probably wrong. First jquery, then bootstrap and your scripts at the end.
Check your local file paths in page source. `Ctrl` + `U` will open  it.
Read about using web console in your browser. Will save you ton of time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Here you go For Offline Bootstrap Dropdown:

1. First download Slim js from `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js`
2. Also you need Popper.js and download from [copy popper.js file](https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js) (download or clone green button) as zip file and extract and inside folder go to dist > esm or umd folder and copy the file to your location
3. And link slim.js(jquery file) and popper.js with your bootstrap js file before body tag ends
4. This works for most of Js components offline(including dropdown/carousel/popover...)
   Enjoy! Try it!(Thank You)